# How better can you rewrite these lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Consider the following class

```
class Person {

private String firstName; 
private String lastName; 
private int age; 
private Address address;

//Assume getters are also available

}
```

lambda #1 : Filter persons of a specific age

```
public List<Person> getPersonsOfAge(int age) {
    List<Person> persons= fillPersonsInfo();
    persons.stream().fiter(person -> person.getAge() == 21).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

lambda #2 : Filter persons with a specific last name

```
public List<Person> getPersonsAboveAge(String name) {
    List<Person> persons= fillPersonsInfo();
    persons.stream().fiter(person -> person.getLastName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

lambda #2 : Filter persons living at the given address

```
public List<Person> getPersonsAboveAge(Address address) {
    List<Person> persons= fillPersonsInfo();
    persons.stream().filter(person -> person.getAddress().equals(address)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How compact can you make these lambdas? Can you reduce all the three lambdas to a single function reference?

Comment: How compact? Rename `person` as `p`, remove white spaces, there at least 15 characters saved. What is the actual problem you're facing and what do you actually want to do?

Comment: The lambda expressions *are* compact. What makes the code look verbose, is the fact, that you are collecting into a `List` three times, first, replicating the code doing this, second, most likely doing it unnecessarily, as you could chain whatever you’re going to do with these lists directly to the stream instead. I bet, `fillPersonsInfo()` follows the same trope, unnecessarily populating a `List` instead of directly returning a stream. By the way, `Collectors.toLost()` most probably produces a `Lost`; if you want a `List` instead, you better use `Collectors.toList()`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a helper method that all your other methods call, and pass in a filter for each type of method

```
 private List<Person> filterPeople(Predicate<Person> filter){
     List<Person> persons= fillPersonsInfo();
     return persons.stream()
           .filter(filter)
           .collect(toList());
 }

 public List<Person> getPeopleOfAge(int age){
     return filterPeople(person -> person.getAge == age);
 }

 public List<Person> getPeopleOfName(String name){
     return filterPeople(person -> person.getName().equals(name));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How compact can you make these lambdas?

As Tunaki said in the comments, remove all whitespaces, rename `person` to `p`. By the way, this question doesn't make sense at all.

> Can you reduce all the three lambdas to a single function reference?

This question can make more sense however. If by that you mean don't be forced to create a new method each time you want to filter on a new predicate you can take a `Predicate` as an argument instead:

```
private static List<Person> getPersonsFilteredOn(Predicate<Person> p) {
    return fillPersonsInfo().stream()
                            .filter(p)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The usage becomes

```
Predicate<Person> agedOf12 = p -> p.getAge() == 12;
Predicate<Person> liveAtFooStreet = p -> p.getAddress().equals(new Address("Foo street"));
Predicate<Person> areCalledBar = p -> p.getLastName().equals("Bar");

List<Person> twelveYearsOld = getPersonsFilteredOn(agedOf12);
List<Person> fooStreetNeighourhood = getPersonsFilteredOn(liveAtFooStreet);
List<Person> barFamily = getPersonsFilteredOn(areCalledBar);
```

The power of this approach comes when you want to *combine* predicates:

```
List<Person> barTeenagersLivingFooStreet = getPersonsFilteredOn(agedOf12.and(liveAtFooStreet).and(areCalledBar));
```